# Disable multiple clicks on save button in jquery-easyui

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-easyui

In easyui while creating a new user how to disable multiple clicks on the save button while the request is sent to php to insert the same in the database

```
function saveUser() {

  $('#fm').form('submit', {
    url: url,

    onSubmit: function() {
      return $(this).form('validate');
    },

    success: function(result) {

      if (result === 'exists') {
        $.messager.alert('Alert', 'Name already exists!\nPlease enter different Name', 'info');
        $('#fm').form('clear');
      } else {
        $('#dlg').dialog('close'); // close the dialog
        $('#dg').datagrid('reload'); // reload the user data
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Till the response doesn't arrive from the php file,I don't want another request to be sent.

Comment: Place your ui code

Comment: What have you tried already? One (to be fair probably not the cleanest one) solution could be to disable the button when it is clicked, get the response, enable the button, return/display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Submit Button as soon as it is clicked,

Please check the below code hope it helps you:

```
function saveUser() {

  $('#fm').form('submit', {

    url: url,

    onSubmit: function() {
       //Code to Disable the submit button comes here.
       $("#SubmitButton").attr('disabled',true);//Assuming SubmitButton is the ID of the button.
      return $(this).form('validate');
    },

    success: function(result) {

      if (result === 'exists') {
        $.messager.alert('Alert', 'Name already exists!\nPlease enter different Name', 'info');
        $('#fm').form('clear');
      } else {
        //If you want to allow the user to click on the Submit button now you can enable here like this :
        $("#SubmitButton").attr('disabled',false);
        $('#dlg').dialog('close'); // close the dialog
        $('#dg').datagrid('reload'); // reload the user data
      }
    }
  });
}
```